# How do I convert a DBQuery<> (or ObjectQuery<>) to a non-collection primitive type (ie: int, string)

Tags: linq, entity-framework

```
var lastitem = Contacts
.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContactID)
.Take(1).Select(p=>p.ContactID);
```

`lastitem` is even though a single item returns a `DBQuery<Int32>`

is there a way to convert it to just a pure `Int32`?

Thanks for the help!

ALSO:

is there a better way to do this? Basically, I'm trying to get an `Int32` type from ContactID from the very last item inside the database

Comment: hmm.. so from the answer below and looking through intellisense closely.. .Select() returns an IQueryable even if it was a single item. That's why it didn't work. So with .First(), it returns a Queryable, which is cast-able to int..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `.First()` (throws if empty) or `.FirstOrDefault()` (returns `0` if empty, or null if you add `.Cast<int?()` first):

```
int lastitem = Contacts.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContactID)
                       .Select(c => c.ContactID)
                       .First();
```

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Yes; he wants the last item.

Comment: But it's tagged EF, and it doesn't support that concept. `OrderByDescending(...).First()` is the way to go. And your text talks `First` but then your snippet goes `Last`, which is what made me ask in the first place.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: EF doesn't support `Last()`? What?

Comment: You will get a `NotSupportedException` at runtime. "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Last[Int32](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: That's so dumb... Fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, SQL doesn't support the idea of `Last`, but it clearly can get you the top 1 (First). The only real option for EF would be to perform an inefficient query (all things considered) to pull everything in and then obtain the last item in memory (perhaps there's a trick it could do at the database, but the point is the query isn't so straightforward). One last thing, the bit about `FirstOrDefault`. If `ContactID` is `int`, it's not going to return `int?`.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: actually, this can easily be done in SQL:
select top 1 *
...
order by ContactID desc;

Comment: @JanCarloViray, you've missed the context of the conversation. Yes, `top 1` is perfectly legal in SQL. The discussion was centered around an actual `Last()` method execution. However, the answer as presented now is obviously correct.